# JPA Fetch Parent Entity Using Child Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have following entity classes, Agent and Client. Where one agent can have multiple clients. (One to Many)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MST_AGENT")
public class AgentEntity
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="agent",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval=false)
    private Set<ClientEntity> clients = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public Set<ClientEntity> getClients()
    {
        return clients;
    }

    public void setClients(Set<ClientEntity> clients)
    {
        this.clients = clients;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }    
}//Agent Entity
```

And ClientEntity as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MST_CLIENT")
public class ClientEntity 
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @ManyToOne
    private AgentEntity agent;

    public AgentEntity getAgent()
    {
        return agent;
    }

    public void setAgent(AgentEntity agent)
    {
        this.agent = agent;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}//Client Entity
```

I get the reference to the Client's primary key in my application. So I am able to find the client entity using entity manager's find API directly.

But after fetching the Client, I need the access to parent AgentEntity.

```
    AgentEntity parentAgent = null;
    ClientEntity clientEntity = null;

    clientEntity = entityManager.find(ClientEntity.class, "2001");
    // Parent Agent is null as well as don't know the Agent Id by anyway
    parentAgent = clientEntity.getAgent();
```

Here now If I will put FetchType.EAGER then only I get the reference to parentAgent else not. I don't want to use EAGER fetching. As I have created kind of bidirectional relationship, I don't get the value of Agent Id too, so that I can find using entity manager's find API. In this case I have to use the Criteria Query.

Please suggest how to load the Parent entity if I have the reference to its child entity.

Comment: You **are** using eager fetching, that's the default for toOne associations. But even if you were not, the parent entity would be loaded lazily as soon as you call a method on parentAgent. So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Agree, It means that whenever I will call clientEntity.getAgent(), It should be loaded. But it is not working like that. I am getting  null Agent.

Comment: That means that the client 2001 you're loading doesn't have any associated agent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was silly mistake in test case.